# Weapons aren't unlocked even after completing all Bell Towers

Tags: far-cry-4

Yesterday I completed all the Radio Towers in Far Cry 4, hoping to unlock one of the signature weapons. However the weapon's page disappointed me by telling me that I need more Bell Towers to liberate. How do I get around this? I have completed all Bell Towers and there are no more to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [not-uncommon bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/2nkxzx/1717_bell_tower_bug/) with Far Cry 4. Sometimes completing collectibles won't award the achievement or weapon it was intended to. In my playthrough I wasn't able to collect the achievement for acquiring all of Mohan's journals, despite otherwise 100%-ing the game. There isn't a workaround to this that I've found. Even uninstalling, reinstalling, and replaying the game didn't fix the bugged achievement for me - and I suspect it wouldn't unlock the weapon for you.

I'm sorry, but I don't think there's anything you can do.

Answer (score -1):

There are several weapons that unlock only if you progress through the main campaign. There are 17 belltowers, make sure you've visited them all. The stores also offer you some weapons so you definitely want to check them out.

Comment: The campaign is complete. Also for some reason the progress of all side missions like Yogi & Reggie, Shanghri-La seems to be locked at 3 despite the fact that I have completed all of them

Comment: Do you have any DLC ?

Comment: Sadly no. I have no DLCs only vanilla far cry 4 with the map editor